# Doubt on bijective function.

Tags: functions

What will the set of all values of $p$ for which the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R=px+\sin x$ is bijective. $p\in\Bbb R$

For $f(x)$ to be bijective it should be strictly monotonic, so that for every $y$ there is only one value of $x$. But how will I solve it graphically? I know how to sketch $x+\sin x$. For different value of $p$ I will have to rotate $x+\sin x$  and find where $f(x)$ is strictly monotonic, but how to determine the accurate values of $p$ because I cannot plot $p$ from $(-\infty,\infty)$.

[Edit]

I have done the corrections now.

Ok let me try calculus here

$f(x)=px+\sin x$

$f'(x)=p+\cos x$

For $f(x)$ to be monotonic it should not have Maxima or minima, so

$f'(x)\neq 0$

$\therefore p \neq -\cos x$

So $p\in\Bbb R-[-1,1]$

Is this the answer?

I know this isn't the answer. Forget calculus part. I got an awesome trick for it. As you know,

$px-1 \leq f(x) \leq px+1$

Now $f(x)$ is similar to a tilted $x+\sin x$ graph which looks like a $\sin x$ graph ploted on $y=x$ instead of x-axis so when $f(x)$ becomes a non-montonic function $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=f(\frac{3 \pi}{2})$ or,

$p ×\frac{\pi}{2}+1=p×\frac{3 \pi}{2}-1$

$\therefore p=\frac{2}{\pi}$

So $p\in\Bbb (\frac{2}{\pi},\infty)$

Similarly when $p<0$

$p ×\frac{-\pi}{2}-1=p×\frac{\pi}{2}+1$

$\therefore p=\frac{-2}{\pi}$

Clubbing up everything to get $p\in\Bbb (-\infty,\frac{-2}{\pi})\cup(\frac{2}{\pi},\infty)$

Is it correct or not?

Comment: Do you know calculus?

Comment: From where to where does $f$ map? What is $p$? Complex, real, an integer?

Comment: I guess you mean that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and that $p\in\Bbb R$. What Clayton means is that you should use calculus to figure out for which $p\in\Bbb R$ the function $f$ is bijective.

Comment: F(x) maps from real to real. Range of p also lies in R

Comment: Yes I know calculus

Comment: Monotonicity surely does not mean $f'(x)\neq{0}$; consider $f(x)=x^3$. But it does mean that one of $f'(x)\geq{0}, f'(x)\leq{0}$ is always true.

Comment: Your answer is almost right. Can $p$ be equal to $\pm 1$?

Comment: @Benedict quite right, thanks BTW $x³$ has a point of inflection at $x=0$

Comment: @Tony it can be $+1$ but not $-1$. I can check individually all values but how to get answer all together.

Comment: Why can't $p$ be $-1$?

Comment: As for your edit, it makes no sense to me! As I said, you were almost right the first time. Now you are way off.

Comment: I m quite right now and I bet I m

Comment: Yes you are right it can be -1. Let me edit further

Comment: Tony if you know how to solve it please write it as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82066/discussion-between-user199925-and-tonyk).